# Oracle table incremental import to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have Oracle table of 520 GB and on this table insert, Update and delete operations are performed frequently.This table is partitioned on ID column however there is no primary key defined and also there is no timestamp column available.

Can you please let me know what is best way I can perform incremental import to HDFS on this table.

Comment: Do you have Oracle GoldenGate? Have you attempted to use Sqoop, if you are going to tag it?

Comment: I tried with Sqoop but as my table doesn't have any modified column, updates and deletes are not part of the incremental import. You can suggest any method which solves my problem.

Comment: Sqoop doesn't need update/delete modifications. It doesn't listen to changes, it is a batch loader

Comment: The official solution by Oracle, I already mentioned. https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/streaming-relational-transactions-to-hadoop-hdfs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please let me is there any method using open source software like Sqoop.

Comment: I don't think "open source" will solve your problem... Sqoop is a unique tool, there is no true replacement for it. Everything I will point you at either connects over JDBC and has similar constraints as Sqoop, or requires a CDC option such as GoldenGate. (Nifi, Streamsets, Kafka Connect). Disclaimer : I've never used an Oracle database http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/bigdata/hadoop-optimal-store-big-data-2188939.html

Comment: 1. https://www.confluent.io/blog/streaming-data-oracle-using-oracle-goldengate-kafka-connect/  2. https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#datacollector/UserGuide/Origins/OracleCDC.html 3.  https://hortonworks.com/blog/change-data-capture-using-nifi/

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on what is your "id" column. If it is generated by ordered sequence, that's easy, just load the table with --incremental append --check-column ID.
If ID column is generated with noorder sequence, allow for some overlap and filter it on hadoop side.
If ID is not unique, your only choice is a CDC tool. Oracle GG, Informatica PWX and so on. There are no opensource/free solitions that I'm aware of.

Also don't need any index to perform incremental load with sqoop but an index will definitely help as its absence will lead to fullscan(s) to the source (and possibly very big) table.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not that hard to solve, just look for some key things in you db.
1. is you column id run by conditions "not NULL and 1=1 ", if so then use sqoop for you task 
using following sqoop tools
--incremental append/lastmodified -check-column [column id]
--split-by [column id] // this is useful if there is not primary key also allows you to run multiple mappers in case of no primary key, you have to specify -m 1 for one mapper only.

prefered way is to do this task using sqoop job using --create tool.
for more information check https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_6
Hope this Helps !